# Magento 2 + create widget via installData Script

Tags: magento2, widget, installdata

I need to custom requirement for creating a widget via Script. but I have facing an error when try to add a widget via below script

```
<?php

namespace Test\Xyz\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup;

class InstallData implements Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
    * @var Setup\SampleData\Executor
    */
    protected $executor;
    /**
    * @var Installer
    */
    protected $installer;

    private $widgetFactory;

    public function __construct(
            Setup\SampleData\Executor $executor,
            Installer $installer,
            \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\InstanceFactory $widgetFactory
    ) {
        $this->executor = $executor;
        $this->installer = $installer;
        $this->widgetFactory = $widgetFactory;
    }

    public function install(Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, Setup\ModuleContextInterface $moduleContext)
    {
        $this->executor->exec($this->installer);

            $instaFeedWidget = [
                'instance_type' => 'Test\Xyz\Block\Widget\Instagram',
                'theme_id' => 2,
                'title' => 'Instagram',
                'store_ids' => '0',
                'widget_parameters' => '{"title":"Instagram ","numberimage":"16","resolution":"standard_resolution"}',
                'sort_order' => 0,
                'page_groups' => [[
                    'page_group' => 'pages',
                    'all_pages' => [
                        'page_id' => null,
                        //'group' => 'all_pages',
                        'layout_handle' => 'cms_index_index',
                        'block' => 'page.bottom',
                        'for' => 'all',
                        'template' => ''
                    ]
                ]]
            ];
        $this->widgetFactory->create()->setData($instaFeedWidget)->save();
    }
}
```

But I am facing error `Test\Xyz\Setup\Installer does not exist`

Any ideas will be welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Xyz\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup;

class InstallData implements Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Setup\SampleData\Executor
     */
    protected $executor;


    private $widgetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Setup\SampleData\Executor $executor,
        \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\InstanceFactory $widgetFactory
    ) {
        $this->executor = $executor;
        $this->widgetFactory = $widgetFactory;
    }

    public function install(Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, Setup\ModuleContextInterface $moduleContext)
    {
        $instaFeedWidget = [
            'instance_type' => 'Test\Xyz\Block\Widget\Instagram',
            'theme_id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Instagram',
            'store_ids' => '0',
            'widget_parameters' => '{"title":"Instagram ","numberimage":"16","resolution":"standard_resolution"}',
            'sort_order' => 0,
            'page_groups' => [[
                'page_group' => 'pages',
                'all_pages' => [
                    'page_id' => null,
                    //'group' => 'all_pages',
                    'layout_handle' => 'cms_index_index',
                    'block' => 'page.bottom',
                    'for' => 'all',
                    'template' => ''
                ]
            ]]
        ];
        $this->widgetFactory->create()->setData($instaFeedWidget)->save();
    }
}
```

I have removed `Installer $installer,` and `$this->installer = $installer;` also variable

```
/**
    * @var Installer
    */
    protected $installer;
```

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: One supplementary question, Layout settings are not able saved, Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason to the error is `Installer` argument in construct function. It needs to be connected with some class like how `$widgetFactory` is done. After that clear code from `generated/code` and run.

Comment: Let me chek that